# Is there a stackalloc function for C?

Tags: c, memory-management, stack

Is there a stackalloc function implemented in C that allows you to allocate a variable length array on the stack, like [stackalloc in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's `alloca` but it's non-standard. Moreover, since C99 there's a feature called "Variable Length Arrays".

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
int v[n]; /* Will fail badly if n is large. */
```

Used **sparingly** and with small values VLAs can be quite nice.

Comment: Thanks, Google had failed me because I basically assumed it would be called stackalloc, and searched stackalloc, and all I could see was for C# :)

Comment: Also, I had tried using VLA's, but they didn't work (on VS2010!). If it's still not supported 10 years after the standard, then I don't know.

Comment: @satuon No, Visual Studio has very limited support for C99.

Answer (score 5):

`alloca` works a little like that, but you need to be very careful using it.